# confidence interval: A/B test - unable to decide what to use

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion, ab-test

I am new to A/B test; I am interested to generate confidence interval in python language. At the moment I have ratio (proportion), for instance, ratio of add to cart to the total sessions in control and experiment variant. I have two code snippets:

**A**

number of success=204,503

number of trials=965,760

```
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportion_confint 
ci_low, ci_upp = proportion_confint(204503, 965760, alpha=0.05, method='normal')
```

`ci_low lower confidence interval  and upper confidence interval`

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794473/calculating-confidence-interval-for-a-proportion-in-one-sample

**B**

```
from scipy import stats
def binomial_ci(x, n, alpha=0.05):
    #x is number of successes, n is number of trials
    from scipy import stats
    if x==0:
        c1 = 0
    else:
        c1 = stats.beta.interval(1-alpha, x,n-x+1)[0]
    if x==n:
        c2=1
    else:
        c2 = stats.beta.interval(1-alpha, x+1,n-x)[1]
    return c1, c2
```

`p1,p2 = binomial_ci(204503,965760)`

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65873479/2740831

I cannot figure out which is what and when to use what.
Subsequently, I will need to generate confidence interval of average order value (AOV), gross margin value (GMV).

Sorry for redundant code and question, however, I do not know whom to reach out. I can blindly use any code but would be interested to know core/logic.

I conduct proportion test as the following:

```
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest
import numpy as np


def conduct_prop_test(sample_success_a,sample_success_b,sample_size_a,sample_size_b):
    #list_sampleA - contains success and trials for variant A
    #list_sampleB - contains success and trials for variant B
    successes = np.array([sample_success_a, sample_success_b]) ## create array/list
    samples = np.array([sample_size_a, sample_size_b])
    stat, p_value = proportions_ztest(count=successes, nobs=samples, alternative='two-sided')
    return(stat, p_value)

##function ends

##how to run

conduct_prop_test(327061,81702,1543914,384635) ## returns a tuple of z-value and p-value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I almost address how to do this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/515728/111259).

The test statistic for a difference in proportions is

$$ z=\frac{p_{1}-p_{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{p_{1}\left(1-p_{1}\right)}{n_{1}}+\frac{p_{2}\left(1-p_{2}\right)}{n_{2}}}}$$

Here, $p_i$ is the estimated proportion in group $i$, so successes divided by trials. A failure to reject the null occurs when $ \vert z \vert < 1.96$.  The way to obtain a confidence interval is then to re-arrange the inequality for $p_1 - p_2$, namely

$$ (p_1 - p_2) \pm 1.96 \sqrt{\frac{p_{1}\left(1-p_{1}\right)}{n_{1}}+\frac{p_{2}\left(1-p_{2}\right)}{n_{2}}} $$

Comment: Thank you for your response and having me directed to detailed response. I am using z proportion test (in python, code shared above) to compare groups (success, trials in both categories). I am unsure if chi-square is the right method in  A/B test.

Comment: @DeathMetal Chisquare would be fine given what you've told me, but I would suggest you compute the difference in proportions and an associated confidence interval.

Comment: Thank you. I will do as guided. :).

Comment: One question on calculation of the Confidence interval (CI). In the formula `(p1-p2)`, does this mean `p1` has to be greater than `p2`? Sorry for asking naive question. Is the order for p1, p2 important?