# Comparing success of group 2 and failure of group 1 (cross-tabulation comparison in contingency table)

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, proportion, fishers-exact-test, z-test

I'm studying the endowment effect through the exchange paradigm. Participants received an object A or B. Then the experimenter asks the participants if they accept to trade their object with the alternative object.

I would like to compare the proportion of participants who refuse to trade A with B, with the proportion of participants who accept to trade B with A. In other words, in a contingency table, I want to compare the proportion of failure of Group 1 with the proportion of success of Group 2. Note that I have a small sample (n < 30).
I don't know tests that allow a direct cross-tabulation comparison like this. I have tried many alternatives (e.g. Fisher's exact test) but they do not allow me to answer this question exactly...

Would you have any ideas or suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason why [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515699/significance-test-for-two-groups-with-dichotomous-variable/515728#515728) answer does not provide you with what you need?